# How to correctly implement methods of a class returning "this" in Managed C++?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++

I have a class with a method which should return the object itself, like doing `return this;` in Java. I tried something like this:

Foo.h:

```
namespace Foo {

    public ref class Bar {
    public:
        Bar quux();
    }
}
```

Foo.cpp:

```
Foo::Bar Foo::Bar::quux() {
    return this;
}
```

The compiler complains: `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'Foo:Bar ^const ' to 'Foo::Bar'`

How do I get this right?

Comment: `this` is a pointer to `Foo::Bar`, using `*this` solves your issue most probably. Please note that the return type should be a `Foo::Bar const&` or just a `Foo::Bar &` to avoid copying the value.

Comment: Then I get: `error C3073: 'Foo::Bar' : ref class does not have a user-defined copy constructor`. However, I do *NOT* want to return a copy, but the object itself

Answer (score 1):

```
   Bar quux();
```

That's pretty likely to be a typo.  Hard to diagnose, the C++/CLI compiler doesn't always produce fantastic error messages.  You should return a *reference* to the `Bar` object, it is a reference type whose objects are stored on the GC heap.  There is no mechanism in .NET to automatically clone objects.  You cannot depend on an auto-generated copy constructor, the kind you might be used to from native C++.  The distinction between reference and value types in .NET is an important one, native C++ does not have that at all and treats all objects as values.  Value types can be copied, reference types can not.

You *can* add the `Bar(const Bar%)` copy constructor to keep the compiler happy, it will automatically use it and stop complaining about quux().  But that's pretty unlikely to be correct if you want to return *this*.  Very high odds that actually meant:

```
   Bar^ quux() { return this; }
```

Note the added ^ hat.

But then again, it is very odd to return *this* since a reference to the object is already required to call quux().  In other words, if you now use `Bar^ foo = obj->quux();` then you can simply write `Bar^ foo = obj;` and be done with it.  No real idea why you are doing this.

Comment: `quux` is probably designed for chain calls, as in `obj->quux()->quuy()` and the meaningful body of `quux` is not in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You should write the following way

```
Foo::Bar const& Foo::Bar::quux() {
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Now getting: `error C3699: '&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'const Foo::Bar'` and `'&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'const Foo::Bar'`